# Tool for REST API JSON response to CSV

Tags: json, csv, rest

I work with a platform that has a robust REST API able to return reports as JSON array.

I am looking for a tool (not a library) that would be able to query REST APIs which authenticate with BASIC AUTH, transform the result into a CSV file, and upload the result onto an SFTP server.

For example I might call this API:

```
curl --user AAA:0000 "https://api.company.io/rewards"

[
  {
    "reward_id":6148678505382750616,
    "fulfillment_id":"PROMO9328a",
    "recipient_email":"april@example.com",
    "recipient_identifier":"00O400000037eWy",
    "reward_type":"coupon",
    "face_value":"10.00",
    "face_value_type":"USD",
  },
  {
    "reward_id":6148678505382710391,
    "fulfillment_id":"PROMO0301a",
    "recipient_email":"may@example.com",
    "recipient_identifier":"00O400000051aQz",
    "reward_type":"coupon",
    "face_value":"20.00",
    "face_value_type":"USD",
  }
]
```

And I want to be able produce this file and place it on an SFTP server:

```
reward_id,fulfillment_id,recipient_email,recipient_identifier,reward_type,face_value,face_value_type
6148678505382750616,"PROMO9328a","april@example.com","00O400000037eWy","coupon","10.00","USD"
6148678505382710391,"PROMO0301a","may@example.com","00O400000051aQz","coupon","20.00","USD"
```

Additional goals:

- Schedule jobs to run, so it could run daily / weekly / etc.
- Ability to go the other way: read a CSV file from an SFTP server and make POST calls to the REST API
- Ability to combine multiple calls.  If an API request returns an id, call a second rest API to get further details on that object to be included in the CSV